# Rotating point feature on line feature in ArcMap

Tags: python, arcmap, field-calculator, rotate

[image]I have a line and a point feature class in ArcMap. I want to rotate the point feature on the line feature. I will use the Symbol Rotate Option with a defined field. I have a script for Field Calculator:

```
def dreh(az,ab,az1,ab1,typ):
    if typ == "tunnel":
        return 0
    elif ab == 0:
        return 90+az
    elif ab1 == 0:
        return 90+az1
    else:
        return 0`

dreh(!azimut!, !Abstand!, !azimut_1!, !Abstand_1!, !typ!)
```

How should I define `azimut`, `azimut_1`, `Abstand`, `Abstand_1`?

The left image is not turned (current state), the right image is turned (desired state).

Comment: This problem requires scripting to populate a field with the angle of rotation for the individual point.  What would help is if you can indicate if the point and line share a common ID value?

Comment: They do not share a common ID value, but every symbol (point) touches "it's" line- So maybe I can connect point and line using some kind of overlap function?

Comment: Are the lines that your points intersect always a straight line composed of 2 vertices, or can they be lines with bends in them, thus composed of multiple vertices?

Comment: Maybe you can calculate an azimuth on each line, spatial join it to the points? https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/calculate-azimuth-of-a-line/idi-p/950738